# Express js render pug|ejs file throws Jquery error

Tags: jquery, express, pug, electron, ejs

i'm having an issue with ExpressJs rendering and Jquery.

my app.js (main file) is

```
restapi=require('express')();
const pug = require('pug');
restapi.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
restapi.set('views', __dirname+'/views');
restapi.set('view engine','pug');
restapi.get("/view/:datalog?",(req, res)=>{
  var datalog=req.params.datalog;
  res.render("index",{title:"Hey",rows:"hello"});

})
```

my index.pug file (i've been using EJS either) is

```
 html
  head
   title= title
   script(src='/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js')
   script.
     window.$ = window.jQuery = module.export;
     $().ready(function(){console.log("READY")});
     (alert("HELOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"))
   body
     rows
```

it throws me an error that can't find jquery module
if i remove the `window.$ = window.jQuery = module.export` (i've tryed even with `= require("jquery"`) instead of module export) the simple javascript shows me the alert.

i've even tryed to link jquery script to the cdn repository. it always gets me error.

i've even tryed moving all the files to the root folder with no public/static assignment.

nothing seems to work...
What am i missing?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you check `/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js` is the valid path to your jQuery file?

Then just use the clean syntax below:

```
html
  head
   title= title
   script(src='/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js')
   script.
     jQuery(function ($) {
       alert('ready');
     });
   body
     rows
```

Comment: as far as i get, it seems that using express and render, it won't use server side (node js) function such as require and so on.
so i moved all the logics to the main js file and the rendered file just for the view.